# Error Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've seen other questions with this kind of error, but none helped me to solve my problem.

I have my personal apple developer account and one from the company I'm working for. When I'm trying to submit an app for my company in order to beta test it I have an error: "Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate". I tried importing developer profile again, but it didn't helped.

Comment: I've seen this comment, as I mentioned before "I've seen other questions with this kind of error, but none helped me to solve my problem." This link is about Xcode beta 2...

Answer (score 1):

Just for documentation purposes: You need to edit your *iOS Provisioning Profile* in [member center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action) and select the correct *Certificate*

Answer (score 0):

delete your own apple id is from Xcode "preferences->Account-> Apple IDs. And Start Archive with your company apple ID.