# Apple id account belonging to two teams getting "Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, software-distribution, code-signing-certificate

**Assumption**: this should not be a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251970/error-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-distribution-certificate), but however is somehow related.

---

I got an **apple id associated to two different teams** and I get the following error:

[image]

This Q/A is not useful for me because it relates to having 2 different app ids. I cannot be removed from one of the two teams and I am pretty sure that there **must be a way to be able to fix this**.

I tried exporting/importing and recreating the developer profile but none of these options helps.

I incur in this error when **I choose Product->Archive** and set my code signing identity to **iOS Distribution**.

I created the iOS Distribution profile and installed it locally.. however the build error say that:

> Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing
>   identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team
>   ID “xxxxxxxxxxxxxx” were found. CodeSign error: code signing is required
>   for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I managed to build the product for archive and then I tried to go on XCode->Archives and selected "**submit to app store**" **as well as** "export" and **Save for Ad Hoc Deployment**. But in both cases I get the error shown below:

[image]

A colleague was telling me that the only way to solve this problems is sometimes to **delete all the key/certificates in the keychain and recreate them all.** However I don't really want to go down this route as I got several and it would be a **pain** (spending then days to reconfigure all the other XCode projects I got...).

I have made sure that I recreated and re-imported the developer and distribution profile for this test.

The purpose is to create a build that I can submit to **iTunes connect** and then distribute via TestFlight. The **iTunes connect** record exists and I am following the [apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW1) on this. This is driving me crazy :-)...

Same happens when I choose "use local signing assets".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to `XCode->Preferences->Accounts` locate your AppleID `View details` on the lower right and try to refresh the list of certificates.

If that doesn't bring the certificate you need then if possible go to the machine where the certificate was requested the first time around and export the identity of that account as a p12 certificate and then installed on your machine.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I forgot to mention that I tried this approach as well. It seems all fine, also I can see the "com.xxxxxx.xxxxx" certificate associated to the account I am using..