# XCode unable to recognise the distribution profile present in my keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution, digital-certificate

In a **nutshell**:

- I got a distribution profile in my keychain (image 1)
- From XCode developer account preferences I see only the developer profile (image 2)
- When I try to add a new iOS distribution profile it says that I already one and that I should visit the member centre (image 3)
- I did so and this brings me back to step 1
- Infinite loop (aka "I'm stuck here as I keep retrying..")

---

**EDIT:** When I try to use the iOS mobile distribution profile that I generated I don't see many options for the code signing identies. This is how it looks like:

[image]

---

I have downloaded the **team distribution profile** on my computer from the apple developer member centre. This is the way it looks in my **keychain**:

[image]

However when I try to sign my code for ad hoc distribution I cannot find the distribution certificate in the code signing identities tab.

I manage to build the product archive (for local ad hoc distribution, e.g. TestFlight) but when I try to export it (or submit it to AppStore) I get a message saying that I already have a code signing identity and that I need to download it. More details on this [in this question that I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158734/apple-id-account-belonging-to-two-teams-getting-your-account-already-has-a-vali).

Today I am trying a different approach and I decided to go to the Account->Preferences and try to click on the "+" button to add a new iOS Distribution profile. This is what I get as response:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately it seems that **XCode is unable to recognise the iOS Distribution profile that I have installed in my keychain** (see beginning of this question) whilst unable to recreate one.

How can I fix this without messing up the certificates/apps of my team members?

Answer (score 1):

**Install both valid certificates in your system (Distribution and Developer)**

Comment: Ah ah, yes sure. But that's what I have been trying to do for days.. I downloaded and installed them (see my question)

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your Keychain screenshot, I can see that the Certificate lacks the little disclosure triangle next to it. What this indicates is that although you have the distribution certificate, you lack the private signing key. Without it you will not be able to sign the app and it is why you're stuck in this loop.

If you were the person that created the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) when setting up the Distribution Certificate, you should have the private key already in your Keychain - in which instance it may be the case that you are using a couple of different Keychains (e.g. I have the **login** keychain as well as my **Development** keychain), the private key is actually in a different keychain to where your distribution certificate is.
In this instance you will simply need to move either your Key or Certificate into the correct keychain for it all to marry up.

Alternatively, if you were not the person that created the Distribution Certificate in the first place, you will need to have the original user export the Key for you using Keychain or by having them export the Developer profile using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if your keychain is missing the private key associated with  distribution certificate.

Here is a similar thread that you may wish to take a look at : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be/2241624#2241624)

good luck!

Comment: There are four possibilities from the screenshot.

1) keychain is missing the private key associated with your iPhone Developer or iPhone Distribution certificate.

2) keychain is missing the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate.

3) Your certificate was revoked or has expired.

4) Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) or Certificate Revocation List (CRL) are turned on in Keychain Access preferences. 

But looking at the screenshot, I presume it's the case 1. 

I provided the link as not possible to copy and paste the solutions from different users from that page.